# How can I hide the status bar on a chromebook?

Tags: android, chromebook

On phones and tablets the status bar and the action bar appear as follows :

[image]

On a chromebook (the one available in the Android Studio emulator, actually), the same layout shows this:

[image]

I understand that the contents of the status bar is not displayed as my app only lies in a window of the chromebook system, but the system seems to still keep space for it inside the app window. Is there a way to *reclaim* that space?

***edit***
I am new to developing app for Chromeboooks. I now realize that what I thought was lost space is in fact a system bar where the icons are not shown (for some reason I do not know).

[image]